# Selecting range of dates from sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i am trying to select some accounts depending on the updating time..

My Table named as account and has columns like `createdOn , updatedOn, acountName` etc.

Now the date is being stored as string `2012-03-20`

How can i make sql query to select diff accounts depending on date.

Here is my code

```
 public ArrayList<Account> getAllAccountsForReports(Date dateTo, Date dateFrom)
  {
      ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
      String queryString = "SELECT * FROM MAAccounts WHERE updatedOn = ? BETWEEN updatedOn = ? ORDER BY accountType, accountName";
      Cursor result =  mDb.rawQuery(queryString, new String[]{ dateToDB(dateTo), dateToDB(dateFrom)});
```

Please tell me how can i correct my sql query.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BETWEEN`syntax is off, what you want is probably;

```
SELECT * FROM MAAccounts 
WHERE updatedOn 
  BETWEEN ? AND ?
ORDER BY accountType, accountName
```

Since you're storing by 'yyyy-MM-dd', between should work well using a string.

I wasn't sure what table name to use since you said it was called `account` in the question and `MAAccounts`  in the code and the columns are mis-spelled in the question, so of course you need to adapt it to your actual column names.